# Shell Redirection causes infinite printing to terminal

Tags: c, shell, redirect

So I am writing a simple shell in C that can do STDOUT redirects. I am reading a string from the user, split it in arguments and then feeding it to exec pretty much. But when I am redirecting the output it 1st: Creates the file I asked for and populates it with the correct data, and then prints the command results in the terminal infinitely. Am I doing something wrong with dup2?

Here is my redirecting code. All the variables used are global, except for the file descriptor.

```
int execRedirectCommand(){
    int fd;

    pid_t pid = fork();


    // fork failed
    if(pid == -1){
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("fork: %s\n", error);
        return -1;
    }
    //Child process
    else if(pid == 0){
        fd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0755);
        if(fd == -1){
            char* error = strerror(errno);
            printf("open:%s\n", error);
            return -1;
        }
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd);

        execvp(payloadArgv[0], payloadArgv);

        // execvp failed
        char* error = strerror(errno);
        printf("pdsh:%s:%s\n", payloadArgv[0], error);
        return -1;
    }
    // Parent process
    else{
        close(fd);
        fileName = NULL;

        // Wait for child process to finish
        int childStatus;
        waitpid(pid, &childStatus, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Fixed a typo in the code nothing major.
**EDIT 2** Including my main:

```
int main(){
    setSigHandler();
    char* user = getlogin();


    while(1){
        printf("[%s]-->$", user);
        getNextCommand(payload);

        if(!strcmp(payload, "\n")) continue;

        if(!strcmp(payload, "close")) break;


        parseCommandString();


        if(fileName != NULL){
            execRedirectCommand();
        }else{
            execSimpleCommand();
        }


    }

    return 0; }
```

Note: commands without STDOUT redirection work just fine.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the colde calling this function? The only thing I can spot that's wrong is that you're closing `fd` in the parend process where it has never been opened/initialized.

Comment: @mata since I am forking doesn't the parent also get a copy of the file? EDIT: added my main.

Comment: @meta well seems that fixed the problem indeed but my question remains: Doesn't the parent get a copy of the file too?

Comment: @Akaitenshi: How could parent know anything about what his child is doing? `fd` has some random value when you close it in the parent process. Remove that line. It is wrong.

Comment: @nsilent22 it seems I was misinformed.. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mata and nsilent22 for pointing that out. The close(fd) in the parent process is not needed.